# How can I save the 'combochangedtext' in a variable?

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
     class FoodChoiceWindow(QWidget):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
         super(FoodChoiceWindow, self).__init__(parent)
         self.setGeometry(250, 100, 400, 400)
         self.setWindowTitle('Food data')
         self.setStyleSheet('Background-color : #F7F7F7')
         self.setUi()

       def setUi(self):
         bkgroundLabel = QLabel(self)
         bkgroundLabel.setGeometry(1, 100, 398, 304)
         bkgroundLabel.setStyleSheet('border: inset')
         bkgroundLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap("../Images/pomegranate.jpg"))
         bkgroundLabel.setScaledContents(True)

         alimentiLabel = QLabel(self)
         alimentiLabel.setStyleSheet('''background-color : #D2D2D2;
                                border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;border-radius: 4px;
                                font : 14px ; padding-left : 5px''')
         alimentiLabel.setText('Selezionare un alimento :')
         alimentiLabel.setGeometry(25, 10, 350, 30)
         alimentiCombo = QComboBox(self)
         alimentiCombo.setGeometry(25, 50, 350, 30)
         foodname = self.loadFoodcombo()
         foodname.sort()
         counter = 0
         for _ in range(0, len(foodname)):
           alimentiCombo.addItem(foodname[counter])
           counter += 1

         alimentiCombo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.tryFunction(param))

       def tryFunction(selfself, p):
         pass

       def loadFoodcombo(self):
         with open('Alimenti.txt', 'r') as rf:
           lines = rf.readlines()[1:]
           hanginglist = []
           for line in lines:
             elements = line.strip().split("\t")
             hanginglist.append(elements[0])
       return hanginglist
```

*I wrote the whole class hoping that it helps you to better find the solution, passing 'param' to the function doesn't work ... I am getting 'unresolved reference param'.  I don't know how to save the changed text of alimentiCombo*

Comment: I already tried alimentiCombo.currentTextChanged.connect(functionName) but it does not work because in the function I cannot read the combo value

Comment: Please edit your question providing the `functionName` you tried, or, better, share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: something like this doesn't work (the combo is unresolved reference)   alimentiCombo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.functionName)
        def functionname(self):
        example = alimentiCombo.currentText()

Comment: I said **edit your question**; don't post code in comments, as they are not formatted and become almost unreadable. [`currentTextChanged()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentTextChanged) already provides the changed text as its argument, add a parameter to the function and you'll get it: `def functionName(self, text): ...`. You can't get a reference to the combo because you didn't set it as an instance attribute, you could do that using `self.alimentiCombo = QComboBox(self)`, but it depends on the situation, and since you didn't provide an MRE I cannot suggest it for every case.